# Russian with Netherlands residency; is a visa needed for UK holiday?

Tags: visas, uk, russian-citizens, freedom-of-movement, dutch-residents

My partner is Russian with a Russian passport, but has a Netherlands residence permit and has lived in the Netherlands for over 7 years.

What is required for her to enter the UK?

Other info which is likely important: her Dutch residence permit needs to be renewed on 27th Feb 2018, and travel to London is 14th February 2018.

She's currently checking into the process for acquiring a Dutch passport but in case it's not completed in time ...

Comment: Are you an EU/EEA citizen? Has your partner lived _with you_ for most or all of those 7 years? Do you own property or raise children together (which would make it easier to demonstrate a "durable relationship" and qualify for the freedom-of-movement rules)? Or does her residence permit say "family member of a union citizen"?

Comment: I'm British, and have lived in Netherlands for almost 3 years. 

My partner has not lived with me or has children/marriage with me or anyone else of EU citizenship

Comment: I have checked here and from what I can tell she can travel under a Standard Visitor Visa - https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Does that sound correct?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It does not ask whether the Dutch residence permit entitles the partner to go to the UK, but for what else she needs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm And the answer to the other question is "No, the residence permit isn't enough. Here's what else she needs." It's a straight-up duplicate.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Duplicates are for when the _question_ is the same. If the answers happen to be the same but the questions are different, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @HenningMakholm There is no fundamental difference between "What do I need?" "You need a visa." and "Can I travel visa-free?" "No, you need a visa." The questions are the same; it's just that one is phrased as a leading question and the other is open. It doesn't make sense to maintain separate answers to these two questions, with the possibility that these answers will become inconsistent over time.

Answer (score 0):

She will need a Standard Visitor visa.

If you had a documentable "lasting relationship" with her, she could possibly qualify for an EEA Family Permit instead (which would be free, in contrast to a visa, and may have easier documentation requirements), but given what you have explained in comments, that doesn't sound likely.

Comment: Perfect Henning, this is what I concluded. Thank you for reaffirming that.